# Layout Updates in theme.xml to pick up parent theme's xml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, parent-child-theme

I've created a theme package called hoi with a default theme.  In the *app/design/frontend/hoi/default/etc/theme.xml* I've set a parent theme to be the a theme we purchased called blacknwhite.

This almost works but it does not pick up the layout.xml from the blacknwhite theme as my own theme's xml overwrites it.  It works when I copy and paste the contents from the blacknwhite theme's xml into my own theme's xml.  But I would rather not do this as so I tried to create a new layout update in my theme's theme.xml.

**theme.xml**

```
<theme>
    <parent>blacknwhite/default</parent>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <hoi_default>
                <!--should be linking to app/design/frontend/hoi/default/layout/parentslocal.xml-->
                <file>hoi/parentslocal.xml</file>
            </hoi_default>

            <hoi_default>
                <!--should be linking to app/design/frontend/hoi/default/layout/local.xml-->
                <file>hoi/local.xml</file>
            </hoi_default>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

This way I hoped to have my own local.xml for my theme which would fall back onto a parentslocal.xml which I would then copy the contents of the parents local.xml to. But it's not working.

I tested it by putting the below in my **local.xml** but it did not work.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I would have thought Magento would inherit from it's parent's theme more seamlessly.

I'm thinking it is perhaps better off putting my sub theme in blacknwhite/hoi!

Comment: So 2 small things, first of all I'm not sure if it allows you to define `<hoi_default>` twice. Second, you cannot name the file `local.xml`. I forgot the source but I can remember that you need to give it another name

Comment: @SanderMangel, even when I add just hoi/parentslocal.xml it doesn't pick up the layout updates in hoi/parentslocal.xml.  I think my syntax must be wrong

Comment: is this test is possible for run in magento?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136861)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem was with my syntax, as per Alan Storms [post on infinite theme's fallaback](https://ericwie.se/blog/magento-infinite-theme-fallback-fix/) the proper syntax is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/enterprise</parent>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <my_new_file_name>
                <file>my_new_file_name.xml</file>
            </my_new_file_name>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

So in my case this meant I needed:

```
<theme>
    <parent>blacknwhite/default</parent>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <parentslocal>
                <!--should be linking to app/design/frontend/hoi/default/layout/parentslocal.xml-->
                <file>parentslocal.xml</file>
            </parentslocal>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```